# No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I tried to pull data on a stock symbol using the Yahoo finance python module. I checked the other questions that are on a similar topic and most of them say to try to run the program during market hours, but that does not help.

This is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
yf.download('QQQ', '2020-01-01', dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This is the error:

```
No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
```

But clearly the symbol exists:

> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue on [`0.2.18`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/releases/tag/0.2.18) (*latest*) :

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                            
2020-01-02  214.399994  216.160004  213.979996  216.160004  212.012711  30969400
2020-01-03  213.300003  215.470001  213.279999  214.179993  210.070663  27518900
2020-01-06  212.500000  215.589996  212.240005  215.559998  211.424179  21655300
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...       ...
2023-05-08  322.420013  324.040009  321.320007  323.690002  323.690002  36465800
2023-05-09  322.000000  322.880005  321.320007  321.640015  321.640015  31768800
2023-05-10  324.119995  326.010010  321.600006  325.140015  325.140015  60368600

[845 rows x 6 columns]
```

You may just need to `pip install --upgrade yfinance`. Or, use this (as per [*GH1268*](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1268#issuecomment-1464906732)) :

```
import pandas as pd;yf.download('QQQ', '2020-01-01', pd.Timestamp.now())
```